# How to place a button relative to an absolute positioned element

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

## PROBLEM

- Can't place the Save and Reset button beneath the canvas.
- You can took a look at the example below. But my canvas has absolute position so I can not use it as a reference to place button beneath.

## MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

- [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/0296yaws/1/)

HTML

```
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Drawing Canvas</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1 class="title">Simple Drawing</h1>
    <p class="title">Click and drag your mouse to draw on the canvas.</p>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button>Save</button><button>Reset</button>
    <script src="canvas.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Recommendation: avoid `position: absolute` for the canvas elements

If it's only to center the canvas, you might not need `position: absolute;` for it. In the snippet below:

- Eliminated `canvas.width = ...` statement, and used CSS to set the width instead.
- Removed `position: absolute;` from `#canvas`, and used `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto;` to horizontally center it
- Added a separate `.buttons` container for optional styling for buttons.

If vertical centering of canvas is a critical requirement, you can still use other CSS layout techniques without `absolute` positioning.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // Get canvas //
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
  // Set canvas context for 2D //
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

  // Modify Canvas size //
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 2
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Simple Drawing</h1>
<p class="title">Click and drag your mouse to draw on the canvas.</p>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div class="buttons">
  <button>Save</button><button>Reset</button>
</div>
```